# Trigger onchange event by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I have this script trimming leading and trailing spaces on input fields

`function trim(el){el.value=el.value.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"").replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ").replace(/\n +/,"\n");return}`

`<input onchange="return trim(this)" type="text" value="">`

and I have to add `onchange="return trim(this)"` in every instance of `<input type="text" value="">` to trigger it. Is it possible to make this script triggered by default without having to add `onchange="return trim(this)"` everywhere? Maybe with some an additional script that tell all input fields to trigger it by default?  I also run jquery on this site if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try jQuery unobtrusive:

```
$("input[type=text]").on("change", function () {
    trim($(this));
});
```

`$("input[type=text]")` this selector will match all inputs of type text on your current page

[fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/qtp7V/)

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. Can you make a jsfiddle.net example?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $(document.ready(function(){
     $('input[type="text"]').change(function(){
          return trim(this);
       });
 });
```